# You may not be eligible to be in this community

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, geography

> Hello everyone! I want to introduce a community that I've joined a
>   long time ago. This community has millions of members that spread
>   throughout the world. Our main focus is simple: "help people every
>   time until they refuse".
>
> This community also have community gatherings. Some of our members routinely meet, but others may never meet because
>   of some issues. For me, I really want to take part in one of the
>   community gatherings that many people said was very exciting in Tokyo,
>   but I'm afraid it's impossible because it's too far away and will cost
>   a lot.
>
> Beside the main activity, like other communities, we also have
>   few extracurricular activities, the most popular are culinary and art
>   class, I feel I quite good at both.
>
> I believe you've heard names of some popular members:
>
> - If you are from Europe, especially from the UK, maybe you know one of our community members. I don't know his real name, people always
>     call him using his initial name, but I'm pretty sure you know his
>     face.
> - If you are American, I know that one of our community members from there has a high rank in the military
> - If you are Asian, I believe you already heard my close friend's name, if I remember correctly, his name is Richard
>
> Unfortunately, even though it has many members, I think most of you aren't eligible to join in this community. But if you think you are qualified, just share your official identification to join us!

What are the qualifications to join them? Are you qualified?

Comment: Is the fellow in Europe's name by any chance rot13(Ovt Ora)?

Comment: @nine9 very nice try! but not, it's not related

Comment: i think i know the europe guy, any hints on the other two? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is the qualification to be:

> A Fast Food Restaurant?

Reasoning:

> In the UK, there is McDonalds (as it's known by) with the mascot of Ronald McDonald
>  In America, there is KFC with the mascot Colonel Sanders
>  In Asia, there is Dicos, which sounds like Dick, a common nickname for Richard.
>  I may have some of the specific restaurants confused, but I'm pretty confident about Colonel Sanders and KFC so if this is not right I think I'm close.

Comment: The 1st one isn't really UK-specific though....

Comment: Are there really "millions" around the world? I guess it's debatable and depends on if you count by singles or by groups.

Comment: I'm sorry but not the intended answer, McDonalds is not UK-specific ;)

Answer (score 2):

Scratch all what I had before. I think it might be:

> A road. Some members routinely meet (intersections), some never do (issues, namely that they're parallel or on different continents/regions of the world). Googleing your username ("malioboro") turns up a street in Indonesia famous for shopping. At first I thought it might be currency, but streets fit more.

"culinary and art class"

> farmers markets typically are on streets in the US. Restaurants and various "arts" are on the street

"many people said was very exciting in Tokyo"

> there was apparently a big party on the street on Halloween in Tokyo. Cost to extend streets is pretty big, especially all the way to Tokyo from Indonesia, so meeting is unlikely there.

If you are from Europe, especially from the UK, maybe you know one of our community members. I don't know his real name, people always call him using his initial name, but I'm pretty sure you know his face.

> I'm not sure what exact street this is talking about, but some Europeans I know of refer to streets by their first name.

"If you are American, I know that one of our community members from there has a high rank in the military"

> Here's where I thought currency would work, because Washington. But really, there's a ton of streets named after generals/admirals here.

"If you are Asian, I believe you already heard my close friend's name, if I remember correctly, his name is Richard"

> Richard Hammond was recently in China, so maybe this works.

"Unfortunately, even though it has many members, I think most of you aren't eligible to join in this community. But if you think you are qualified, just share your official identification to join us!"

> Just tell us the streetname we share? I guess share a map of the location. I am not qualified to join. The qualifications are to have a street named after us.

Comment: I believe that I might be on the right track @malioboro

Comment: wow.. you're on the right track! I don't know why someone gives you a downvote, you are partially correct, I realized the American part is too broad, I'll give you additional hint: rot13("ur vf snzbhf sbe uvf fuvavat onqtr")

Comment: I think that hint might actually be confusing me more than helping. Might help someone else out though.

Comment: Really like this answer. I would add two things : rot13(znyvbobeb fgerrg vf snzbhf sbe erfgnhenagf naq negvfgf, juvpu tbrf jryy jvgu ner naq phyvanel pynff) and rot13(zrrgvat va Gbxlb znl or n ersrerapr gb Fuvohln Pebffvat ?)

Answer (score 0):

I am qualified as I am

> a member of PSE

1st guy:

> chasly from UK [face reads 10:10]

2nd guy:

> 

3rd guy:

> 

Comment: @malioboro am i on the right track? thanks!